# encoding in R with utf-8 mistake?

Tags: r

I cannot see why is this result produced

```
bbddcost$GC[1]
[1] "DAÑOS"

Encoding(bbddcost$GC[1])
[1]   "UTF-8"

Encoding("DAÑOS")
[1] "UTF-8"

bbddcost$GC[1]=="DAÑOS"
[1] FALSE

> Sys.getlocale()
[1] "LC_COLLATE=Spanish_Spain.1252;LC_CTYPE=Spanish_Spain.1252;LC_MONETARY=Spanish_Spain.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=Spanish_Spain.1252"
```

I need to have a true in this comparison but apparently i am missing something. could you help me?

Comment: you know you have an additional e in the first line?

Comment: sorry about that, but has nothing to do with the solution, many thanks though

Comment: No problem, I was thinking that could be more the source of your problem than the solution

Comment: Are you copy pasting from a Web browser or using Windows? Try `charToRaw` on both your quoted object and the final object.

Comment: sorry, I can't replicate this in r studio, it may be because im copying direct from the browser, but I get encoding = "latin1"

Comment: Nevermind, it should be sth wrong with my R session. I just reset Rstudio and now it works perfect. Thank you very much